# how to unrender an autocomplete if once it is renderd

Tags: autocomplete, yui, yui3

I have text-field on which i have attached the Auto-complete plugin (Y.Plugin.AutoComplete)
what I do is  to render it once other fields above it are checked.

My question is once the above fields are checked and the Auto-Complete is rendered but again if the user goes back and enters something incorrect then this time i have to stop the Auto-Complete from displaying suggestions again.

I have tried render:"false" but that did no help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Autocomplete plugin by using `node.unplug()`.

```
input.ac.render();

otherNode.on('click', function () {
  if (someCondition) {
    input.unplug(Y.Plugin.Autocomplete);
  }
});
```

Comment: No problem. Just mark the answer as correct if it helped you, please.